# Array of Arrays in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, angular

I'm trying to add an object array to an array in TypeScript (for an Angular 2 app). Here's a stripped down and simplified version of my code:

mylist.ts:

```
export class myList {
    constructor(
        Number1: number,
        String1: string
    ){}
}
```

mylist.component.ts:

```
import { myList } from './myList';

export class ProductDetailComponent { 

    myNumber: number;
    myString: string;

    myList: Array<myList>;

    constructor() {
        this.myNumber = 10;
        this.myString = "some text";
    }

    addNavigation() {
        this.myList = [ new myList(this.myNumber, this.myString) ];
        console.log(JSON.stringify(this.myList));
    }

}
```

Output:

```
[{}]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `myList` is an object, not an array, this is expected behaviour

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not binding to a property of `MyList` thus your object is empty.

Change your class to the following

```
export class myList {
    constructor(
        public Number1: number,
        public String1: string
    ){}
}
```

By adding `public` or `private` TypeScript will create properties for you.
Now the result will be:

```
[{Number1: val, String1: val}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You never set properties of the myList object in its constructor. Try this:

```
export class myList {
    constructor(Number1: number, String1: string) {
        this.number = Number1;
        this.string = String1;
    }
}
```