# How to push elements in an Array of Array in Typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm new to typescript. I've created a `Monthpicker` widget in Angular. Originally, It is very complicated and have lots of functionalities. So, I'll try to keep it as simple as possible. Here is my code.

**monthpicker.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  ...
})
export class AppComponent  {

  monthsViewSlices: Array<Array<number>>;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.monthsViewSlices = [[0, 24], [6, 30], [18, 42], [30, 54], [42, 66], [54, 78]];
    console.log(this.monthsViewSlices);
  }
}
```

And these `monthViewSlices` are actually slices like this:

[image]

Month indexes are starting from 0. As you can see I've hard-coded slices as follows:

`this.monthsViewSlices = [[0, 24], [6, 30], [18, 42], [30, 54], [42, 66], [54, 78]];`

Which is not a very good thing to do. I want to make this configurable using `for` loops. I tried this code:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    const lowerBound=2012;
    const upperBound=2015;
    let x;
    let y;
    let z;
    let iterations=upperBound-lowerBound;
    for(x=lowerBound; x<=upperBound; x++) {
      for(y=0; y<=24; y++) {
        //DO NOTHING JUST ITERATE
      }
      this.monthsViewSlices.push([0,y]);
    }
    console.log(this.monthsViewSlices);
  }
```

But I don't know how to deal with `Array<Array<number>>`. I also tried taking help from these:

1. [“push()” to an array in Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36667055/push-to-an-array-in-typescript)
2. [How to Push object in an array of array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41998474/how-to-push-object-in-an-array-of-array)
3. [typescript push elements into an array in roundrobin fashion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46442789/typescript-push-elements-into-an-array-in-roundrobin-fashion)
4. [Array of Arrays in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37586489/array-of-arrays-in-typescript)

Simple `push()` method will not work here. That I've tried. Or mayne not in the correct way. So, I've to a lot of gymnastics here.

But I'm not able to make this dynamic instead of hard coding.

Following things should be taken care of:

1. Number of slices are equal to number of `iterations` which is `upperBound-lowerBound`
2. Difference between first and second slice is 6 while for rest it is 12:
   [image]

I've created a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mgtunt) also. Please someone help me achieve this. Let me know if more details are required to this question. And also tell me if it is even doable or I am wasting my and everyone's time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've read your example correctly, you want 3 "slices" (the difference between 2012 and 2015 in this case), resulting in

```
[0, 24]
[6, 30]
[18, 42]
```

I've forked your stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ug7f5f)

You weren't wrong with how you were manipulating your arrays (I personally prefer to type arrays as [] rather than Array<>, but that's just a personal preference), the loop logic just needed a little help.

Edit:
Code from the stackblitz fork:

```
  years: number[] = [];
  monthsViewSlices: number[][] = [];

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const lowerBound=2012;
    const upperBound=2015;

    let x = 0;
    let y = 24;
    let iterations=upperBound-lowerBound;
    for(let i=0; i<iterations; i++) {      
      this.monthsViewSlices.push([x, y]);
      const increment = i === 0 ? 6 : 12;
      x+=increment;
      y+=increment;

    }
    this.monthsViewSlices.forEach(slice => console.log(slice));
  }
```

Comment: Absolutely correct Sir. Give me 10 mins. Let me put this ins the actual project, test it and then i'll get back to you. :-)

Comment: This is perfect Sir. But still I want to keep it  `monthsViewSlices: Array<Array<number>>` only. And with that, I'm getting this error: `ERROR TypeError: "this.monthsViewSlices is undefined"`. I have edited my stackblitz. Can you please look at it.

Comment: Your choice :) You need to initialize it: ```monthsViewSlices: Array<Array<number>> = [];```

Comment: I just don't know how to thank you for this. This literally made my day. You just cured my headache. :-)

Answer (score 0):

First, create an empty array like this `let month: string[] = [];`, you can use const or let, if you are declaring inside the function use let, otherwise use const or var, it's all up to you.

you have an array `this.monthsViewSlices = [[0, 24], [6, 30], [18, 42], [30, 54], [42, 66], [54, 78]];`
and in case you want the specific element to push in the new array you can use something like this.

```
    for(let month in monthsViewSlices){ 
       if monthsViewSlices[month].includes(value/condition) === true){
          month.push(monthsViewSlices[month])
          } 
        }
```